# requesting excel services rest from console application but the server returns error code 403 forbidden

Tags: rest, excel-services

I just want to access an excel document in SharePoint, which is possible through **excel services**. I've written the following code for that

but still it is giving me error of **403 forbidden**.

My code:

```
         using System;
         using System.Collections.Generic;
         using System.Security;
         using System.Net;
         using System.Runtime.Serialization;
         using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
         using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;

        namespace ConsoleApplication1
        {
          class Program
          {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
              try {
                //Console.WriteLine("Enter the sharepoint online UserName...");
                String username = "username";
                const string password = "password";
                SecureString pass = new SecureString();
                foreach (char itemC in password.ToCharArray())
                {
                    pass.AppendChar(itemC);
                }
                //pass.MakeReadOnly();
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine(pass);
                SharePointOnlineCredentials cred = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(username, pass);
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Requesting the REST...");
                String url ="https://serverhosr_url/sites/sitename/_vti_bin/ExcelRest.aspx/Shared%20 Documents/Template.xlsb/Model/Ranges?$format=json";

            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            req.Credentials = cred;
            req.Headers["X-FORM_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED"] = "f";
                Console.WriteLine(req.ToString()); 
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
            DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(RangeResponse));
            RangeResponse rr = ser.ReadObject(response.GetResponseStream()) as RangeResponse;
               Console.WriteLine("the response is as follows.."+rr.rows[0][0].fv);
               Console.ReadLine();
               }
               catch (NotSupportedException) { }
              }
            }
            [DataContract]
            public class CellValue
            {
             [DataMember]
              public object v { get; set; }
             [DataMember]
             public object fv { get; set; }
            }
             [DataContract]
            public class RangeResponse
            {
            [DataMember]
            public String name { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public CellValue[][] rows { get; set; }
          }
        }
this is giving error at line where the code is HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
```

Answer (score 1):

Pavan, I guess your code is the result of the implementation of [this](https://blogs.office.com/2013/12/17/excel-rest-api-in-sharepoint-online/).

I have done it and I could connect successfully with my user, password & tenant information.

What I can see in the URL is that there is a space in `"/Shared%20 Documents/"` that needs to be eliminated.

Also you haven't specified the range itself like:

```
/Model/Ranges**('A1')**
```

Hope you find it useful.
Kind Regards